# I can't import Yup with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

ExampleComponent.js:

```
import ExampleValidator from '../validators/exampleValidator.js';
import User from '../models/user.js';

console.log("a");

let engin = new User(1, "Engin", "Demiroğ", "Ankara", 36)

let exampleValidator = new ExampleValidator();
// exampleValidator.checkValidity(engin);
```

EmployeeValidators.js:

```
import * as Yup from '../../node_modules/yup/lib/index.js';

export default class EmployeeValidators {
    constructor(){
        const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
            id: Yup.number().required('Id is required'),
            firstName: Yup.string().required('First name is required'),
            lastName: Yup.string().required('Last name is required'),
            age: yup.number().required().positive().integer(),
            city: Yup.string().required('City is required')
        });
    }

    // checkValidity(employee) {
    //     return validationSchema.isValid(employee);
    // }
}
```

[Browser output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3N3b.png)

Browser output text:
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Error evaluating http://localhost:3000/src/validators/exampleValidator.js
Error evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/yup/lib/index.js
exports is not defined
at execute (index.js:7)
at B (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1177)
at E (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1238)
at E (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1222)
at E (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1222)
at D (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1201)
at C (es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:1194)
at es6-module-loader-dev.src.js:855

Comment: Isn’t it a bit of an anti-pattern to be loading things directly from `node_modules` instead of transpiring your code correctly…?

Comment: Is `import * as Yup from 'yup';` not working for you?

Comment: @esqew i'm sorry, i don't know.

Comment: @HassanImam yes, doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, you are loading in browser, are you using react. If not you can use script tag to load yup from this url `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/yup@0.32.11/lib/index.min.js`

Comment: @HassanImam i add this source in index.html but i get new error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at index.js:3
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Yup is not defined

Comment: Please use `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/yup@0.32.11/lib/index.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: What are you not understanding about `404 Not Found`? The server can't find `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/yup`. Apparently you're using [a polyfill](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader) for ES6's native module loading for some reason. If you are using a browser other than really old IE, don't do that. Make sure you are loading your scripts as modules though, using `type="module"` on the `script` element.

Comment: I add this code in index.html but not working. I not use Reach. My project codes is here: https://github.com/furkanartar/JavaScript-Intro/tree/main/src @HassanImam

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are expected to be self-contained; @HassanImam and others shouldn't have to go to GitHub or anywhere else to answer your question. Add a [mre] here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i updated.  Is it true now?

Comment: @HassanImam I updated the codes, can you check again?